# eXtended Merkle Signature Scheme (XMSS) vs Leighton-Micali Signature (LMS)

Tags: hash, signature, hash-signature

Very briefly, how does [eXtended Merkle Signature Scheme (XMSS)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/484) stack up against [Leighton-Micali Signature (LMS)](https://www.google.com/patents/US5432852)?

Comment: If you want people to find your linkedin, please use your profile page and not your posts. Also why did you link to your article (I just assumed it's for context, but this may be wrong)?

Answer (score 4):

- They have provable security in different models; XMSS in the concrete model, LMS in the random oracle model
- LMS is about 3 to 5 times faster than XMSS (assuming that the messages are short)

I suspect that, if you use a stateful signature scheme in a block chain solution, neither difference is that significant.

The two standards also allow different sets of tree heights/Winternitz parameters, but there's nothing inherent in the two ideas to restrict things. I'm pretty sure that if have your heart set on one parameter set that works great for your application, you can ask the authors for it.

Comment: Truly random strings cannot be compressed, as a matter of information theory. The random oracle model, however, allows random strings to be compressed. This property is explicitly used by the LMS spec. So, somehow something "impossible" is happening, but - nonetheless - there are no known attacks. (Presumably, the random oracle model is standing in for a computational security argument that isn't fully described.) See the last page of https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-208.pdf for some further text I wrote about the difference. (I think LMS is fine.)

Comment: Note that XMSS is not "entirely" in the concrete model. If you want quantum security, it seems XMSS requires a quantum random oracle assumption at some point. (If this has changed, or if what was said in 800-208 is wrong, please let me know!)

Comment: @DanielApon: IIRC, in XMSS the initial message hash isn't covered by the concrete model proof - is that what you're referring to?